# 'E2250: There is no overloaded version of...' on miss-typed generic identifier

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

My code (reduced to the snippet below) does not compile. Delphi XE4's compiler returned this message: `E2250: There is no overloaded version of 'Sort' that can be called with these arguments`.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TSomeGenericType<TKey, TData> = class (TObject);

function GetSortedArray: TArray<TSomeGenericType<Integer, TObject>>;
begin
  // ... omitted code to initialize Result
  TArray.Sort<TSomeGenericType<Integer, TObject>(Result); 
  // !!! E2250: There is no overloaded version of 'Sort' that can be called with these 
  // arguments
end;

begin
end.
```

Comment: Feels like a compiler bug as presented. What is TSomeType? What delphi version?

Comment: Plausible workaround is to use a local variable, pass that to Sort, and then assign to Result. Perhaps the compiler is confused by Result here. I also wonder why there's no MCVE.

Comment: Your edit is something of a disaster. None of your code remotely compiles. I urge you to make an MCVE. I see no evidence of a compiler bug.  All I can see is that you have a problem that you have yet to demonstrate to us. As such this question is off-topic at present.

Comment: It's not a bug, the error was caused by a typo of mine. I will edit the question and provide an answer shortly. @DavidHeffernan, you are totally right on the MCVE, as I started creating one I recognized my error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think it might be interesting though, as the error message is extremely misleading on this one. Let me present it. Then we can delete the question if necessary.

Comment: OK, let's see what you've got. I trust that the MCVE will be a simple console application.

Comment: Yeah, you are missing a >. It's nice that you've had a practical demonstration of the power of the MCVE! ;-) Thanks for listening! Oh, I also cut down the code to make it a more concise MCVE. That's also really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments to this question the error's cause is a tiny typo. Instead of

```
TArray.Sort<TSomeGenericType<Integer, TObject>(Result);
```

it should be

```
TArray.Sort<TSomeGenericType<Integer, TObject>>(Result);
```

I'd think, the parser should note that **before** checking if there is an function with a compatible signature.